# Cordova-plugin-fcm FCMPlugin notification toast while in background

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm for a project at the moment and I was wondering if there was a way for a cordova application running in the background to:

a. show a toast popup when notifications arrive. (not just in the notification bar but an alert toast in the middle of the screen)

b. wake up the screen if the screen if the screen has been turned off.

c. change the color of the toast/notification via the cordova plugin

for both android and iOS.

if it's not possible to do it via stock plugin, is there a way to reach the cordova-plugin-fcm team directly? Or a easy config file in the plugin?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple way to contact developers: https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues

Comment: Ah, thanks for the suggestion. I didn't think this was an 'issue' per say, but I guess I should have tried this first.